# implementing an OAuth2 provider with Grails

Tags: grails, oauth, spring-security

I'm trying to implement a Grails app that provides OAuth2 using the [Spring Security OAuth2 Provider](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth2-provider) plugin. [The provider app](https://github.com/domurtag/oauth2-provider) and a [client app](https://github.com/domurtag/oauth-client) that I use to test it, are both available on GitHub.

I've followed the [instructions in the plugin's docs](http://bluesliverx.github.io/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider/docs/guide/gettingStarted.html), that explain how to implement a provider. To test it, I saved the following oauth client and user in `Bootstrap.groovy`

```
def init = { servletContext ->

    def saveArgs = [flush: true, failOnError: true]

    def userRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(saveArgs)
    def clientRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_CLIENT').save(saveArgs)

    // create an OAuth client
    new Client(
            clientId: 'my-client',
            authorizedGrantTypes: ['authorization_code', 'refresh_token', 'implicit', 'password', 'client_credentials'],
            authorities: ['ROLE_CLIENT'],
            scopes: ['read', 'write'],
            redirectUris: ['http://localhost:9090/oauth-client/auth/callback']
    ).save(saveArgs)

    // create a regular user
    def user = new User(username: 'me', password: 'password').save(saveArgs)
    UserRole.create user, userRole, true
}
```

In the client app, I click on the following link that initiates the authorization code grant flow

```
<g:set var="redirectUrl" value="${g.createLink(controller: 'auth', action: 'callback', absolute: true)}"/>
<h2>
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/oauth2-provider/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=my-client&scope=read&redirect_uri=${redirectUrl}">OAuth Login</a>
</h2>
```

I enter the username and password of the above user in the login form, then click the "Authorize" button shown in the confirmation dialog thereafter. An authorization code is successfully returned to the client app, but when it tries to exchange this for an access token the following error occurs

> invalid_scope: Empty scope (either the client or the user is not allowed the requested scopes)

The code used to exchange the authorization code for an access token is shown below.

```
String getAccessToken(String authCode) {

    def url = 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2-provider/oauth/token'

    def params = [
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            code: authCode,
            client_id: 'my-client'
    ]

    new HTTPBuilder(url).request(POST, JSON) {
        uri.query = params

        response.success = { resp, json ->
            json.access_token
        }

        response.failure = { resp, json ->
            log.error "HTTP error code: $resp.status, status line: $resp.statusLine, "

            json.each { key, value ->
                log.error "$key: $value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The link that initiates the OAuth process requests access to the `read` scope. This *is* included in the `scopes` property of the `Client` object, so there's no obvious reason why access to this scope should be prohibited.

You can reproduce the error by following these instructions:

- Start the provider app with `grails run-app`
- Start the client app on port 9090 with `grails run-app -Dserver.port=9090`
- On the homepage of the client app click the "OAuth Login" link. This redirects to the provider app and prompts you to login. Enter the username "me", password "password", and click the "Authorize" button in the confirmation dialog that follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles across this in the future:

This was the result of a small bug in the plugin. The temporary workaround is to include the scope parameter in the token endpoint request with the same value as the scope parameter sent to the authorization endpoint.

See [issue #64](https://github.com/bluesliverx/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider/issues/64) on the plugin's GitHub repository for more details about the problem.